# How to write IN type query in android(pre-populated database)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a query in which I have multiple ***In statements***.

***Query***

---

select TCF.Car_Make,TCF.Car_Model,TCF.Car_Ver,Prices,Rear_Parking_Sensors,Airbags,Engine_Immobilizer,Power_Windows,Integrated_In_Dash_Music_System,Steering_Adjustment from Car_Feature AS TCF JOIN  Car_Spec AS TCS where TCF._id=TCS._id and TCS.Prices between '0' and '80,00,00,000' and TCS.Fuel_Type ***IN***("Petrol","Diesel","null","null") and TCF.Car_Make ***IN***("null","null","null","null","null","null","null","Force Motors","Ford","Hindustan Motors","Honda","null","null","Lamborghini","Land Rover","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null")

---

My Query works perfectly fine when i execute it in Sqlite browser.

But when I try to execute the same query in my helper class using ***db.execSQL()*** statement it doesn't work.

My Logcat shows error

```
07-31 05:06:03.085: E/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: Queries cannot be performed using execSQL(), use query() instead.
```

It says to use ***db.query()*** statement.

The confusion is how to i use ***IN*** statement in ***db.query()***

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that you cannot use SQLiteDatabase.execSQL() to perform a Select or any other SQL statement that returns data. From the SQLiteDatabase.execSQL() doc:

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data. It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(String, String, ContentValues), update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]), et al, when possible.

Edit: You can use the rawQuery() to form your parameterized query as in:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM table"
+ " WHERE name IN ("+ createPlaceholders(names.length) +")";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, names);
```

In this case let's assume that createPlaceholders() returns a String containing names.length comma separated '?'.